# Can I use let in guards on Haskell?

Tags: haskell

right now I have an error that says  parse error on input ‘|’ that refers to the '|' before the if statement. 
I am also not sure if I can use let in guards like the code below.
The code below is an example to my problem, please help to correct my mistakes, thank you in advance!

```
func x y
   | let 
       sum = x + y
       mult = x * y
   | if sum == 3
       then do
            sum+=1
       else if mult == 5
           then do
                mult -=1
```

Comment: You don't need guards here

Answer (score 5):

In fact, Haskell2010 allows the `let` expression to appear in the guard. See the report [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13). `|let decls` introduces the names defined in `decls` to the environment.

For your case, we can write

```
fun x y 
  | let sum = x + y, sum == 3 = Just (sum + 1)
  | let mult = x * y, mult == 5 = Just (mult - 1)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Oh, nice, I forgot about that. Too bad the `let` scope does not include later branches, i.e. we can't use `sum` after the second guard starts.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, we can not do that with `let`.

More precisely, we can write

```
func x y | let z = .. in condition = result
         | otherCondition          = otherResult
```

but `z` will only be visible in `condition`, and not in `result`, `otherCondition` or `otherResult`.

(This can be improved using pattern guards, but not completely: `z` will still be unavailable in `otherCondition` and `otherResult`)

The solution is using `where` instead:

```
  func x y | condition      = result
           | otherCondition = otherResult
           where z = ...
```

Here, `z` is visible everywhere.

(Personally, I dislike this form of `where` because it is too far from the uses of `z`, but I can't see any simple alternative in this case.)

Finally, let me add that your code does not look functional to me: there's no `if then` without `else` in functional programming, and `mult -= 1` can not modify variable `mult` (the same holds for `sum += 1`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `let` in the top however it has to be followed by an `in` to designate the block where the defined values are to be used. Also you are missing the condition about what to do if `sum /= 3` and `mul /= 5`. So may be returning a `Maybe` type could be better such as

```
func :: Integral a => a -> a -> Maybe a
func x y = let sum = x + y
               mul = x * y
            in case (sum, mul) of
               (3, _) -> Just (sum + 1)
               (_, 5) -> Just (mul - 1)
               _      -> Nothing
```